# Modded Command in Minecraft 1.15.2 constantly says Unknown command when argument is given

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I'm currently trying to develop a simple Minecraft mod for 1.15.2. What I'm trying to create is a command that anonymizes your messages, for example during fake elections. It basically takes the message that you wrote, and it sends it anonymously to everyone in the server.

Here's the code for the command class that handles the behaviour:

```
public class CommandVote {
    public static void register(CommandDispatcher<CommandSource> dispatcher) {
        LiteralArgumentBuilder<CommandSource> builder = Commands.literal("vote").requires(source -> source.hasPermissionLevel(0));
        builder.executes(context -> vote(context))
                    .then(Commands.argument("message", MessageArgument.message()))
                        .executes(context -> voteArgs(context));
        dispatcher.register(builder);
    }

    private static int vote(CommandContext<CommandSource> context) throws CommandSyntaxException {
        ServerPlayerEntity player = context.getSource().asPlayer();
        player.sendMessage(new StringTextComponent("Por favor, introduzca su opcion en la votacion"));
        return Command.SINGLE_SUCCESS;
    }

    private static int voteArgs(CommandContext<CommandSource> context) throws CommandSyntaxException {
        ServerPlayerEntity player = context.getSource().asPlayer();

        player.server.getPlayerList().sendMessage(MessageArgument.getMessage(context, "message"));
        return Command.SINGLE_SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

The command registers and it shows up in game. The problem comes when I try to execute it like for example: "/vote hello". Every time an argument is added to the command, Minecraft just tells me the command doesn't exist or "Unknown Command"

I don't quite understand what I'm messing up here. Any advice in the right direction is really appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the question! This could work better as body of the top function:

```
LiteralArgumentBuilder<CommandSource> builder = Commands.literal("vote")
                .then(Commands.argument("number", IntegerArgumentType.integer())
                        .then(Commands.argument("message", MessageArgument.message())
                                .executes(context -> {
                                    System.out.println("Level 3 " + context.getInput());
                                    return Command.SINGLE_SUCCESS;
                                }))
                        .executes(context -> {
                            System.out.println("Level 2 " + context.getInput());
                            return Command.SINGLE_SUCCESS;
                        }))
                .executes(context -> {
                    System.out.println("Level 1 " + context.getInput());
                    return Command.SINGLE_SUCCESS;
                });
dispatcher.register(builder);
```